# google.visualization.DataTable displays wrong date (month +1)

Tags: jquery, datatable, visualization

I am using google's visualization.DataTable() to create a table.

Using the date '2017/04/01' in my data will result in displaying '01.05.2017' in the output.

It increases the month by 1 but I have no idea whats wrong here. Any ideas?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["table"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

  function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var cssClassNames = {
        'headerRow': 'header-row',
        'headerCell': 'header-cell',
        'tableCell': 'table-cell'
    };             
    data.addColumn('date',   'myDate');
    data.addRows([[new Date(2017,4,1)]]);           
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div')); 
    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, allowHtml: true, 'cssClassNames': cssClassNames, width: '100%'});
  }                        
</script> 
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, the month parameter is a 0-based.
So you should try:

```
data.addRows([[new Date(2017,3,1)]]);
```

> **month**
>
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for
>   January to 11 for December.

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date